# Handling View Model in Post Method of Edit page

Tags: asp.net-mvc, viewmodel

I am trying to modify the activity edit page so that I can involve more information. 
To simplify, I have the following.

Model

```
public class Activity
{
    public int ActNo { get; set; }
    public string ActName { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Attendance> Attendances { get; set; }
}

public class Attendance
{
    public int ActNo { get; set; }
    public string StudentID { get; set; }
    public virtual Activity Activities { get; set; }
    public virtual Student Students { get; set; }
}
public class Student
{
    public string StudentID { get; set; }
    public string EnglishName { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Attendance> Attendances { get; set; }
}
```

In edit page, I want to display student information (include those don't have related record in Attendance) as well. So I have a ViewModel.

```
public class ActivityEditView
{
    public Activity SelectedActivity { get; set; }
    public Student Students { get; set; }
}
```

View

```
@model <projectname>.ViewModels.ActivityEditView
@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()

    <div class="form-horizontal">
        <hr />
        @Html.ValidationSummary(true, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.SelectedActivity.ActNo)

        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.SelectedActivity.ActName, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.SelectedActivity.ActName, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.SelectedActivity.ActName, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
                <input type="submit" value="Save" class="btn btn-default" />
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

I changed model.ActNo and model.ActName to model.SelectedActivity.ActNo and model.SelectedActivity.ActName

Controller

```
    [HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public ActionResult Edit([Bind(Include = "ActNo,ActName")] Activity activity)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            db.Entry(activity).State = EntityState.Modified;
            db.SaveChanges();
            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }
        return View(activity);
    }
```

Everything now displays correctly but I could not update the information.
Error occurs at db.SaveChanges().

Store update, insert, or delete statement affected an unexpected number of rows (0). Entities may have been modified or deleted since entities were loaded.

I don't know how to update the code in controller part. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to modify your class (**Activity**) to specify the bindable attributes as following:

```
[Bind(Include = "ActNo,ActName")]
public class Activity
{
    public int ActNo { get; set; }
    public string ActName { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Attendance> Attendances { get; set; }
}
```

then in your POST action you need to pass an entity of the view model which is of type (**ActivityEditView**):

```
[HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public ActionResult Edit(ActivityEditView activityEdit)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            db.Entry(activityEdit.SelectedActivity).State = EntityState.Modified;
            db.SaveChanges();
            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }
        return View(activity);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You might be binding to a `null`. Try:

```
[Bind(Prefix = "SelectedActivity")]Activity activity
```